# cygwin uniq not working

Tags: sorting, cygwin, uniq

Given the following sorted file (myfile.txt):

```
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photolisting/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
```

When I try:

```
uniq -c myfile.txt
```

I get:

```
21 http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photoListing/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
   1 http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photolisting/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
```

Which I guess might indicate a hidden character or something - but when I try:

```
uniq -u myfile.txt
```

I get the expected:

```
http://quarterly.mayo.edu/photolisting/default.cfm?summary=&displaymode=&reporting_unit_code=
```

Is this a bonafide inconsistency, or am I missing something?
Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 1):

`uniq -u` only prints unique lines. Your `myfile.txt` apparently has 21 identical lines followed by one *unique* line. `uniq -u` prints only that one unique line.

`uniq myfile.txt` should print two lines, the first corresponding to the 21 identical lines and the second corresponding to the final non-matching line.

For example:

```
$ ( echo foo ; echo foo ; echo bar ) | uniq -c
      2 foo
      1 bar
$ ( echo foo ; echo foo ; echo bar ) | uniq -u
bar
$
```

As for why `uniq -c` is producing 2 lines of output rather than 1, it's because your last line is different from the preceding 21 lines. You have `photoListing` (uppercase `L`) on lines 1..21 and `photolisting` (lowercase `l`) on line 22.

(My first thought was that you probably had some hidden characters in the file; since you're on Cygwin, inconsistent line endings are the most likely culprit. To see the hidden characters:

```
uniq -c myfile.txt | cat -A
```

But it turns out that's not the problem.)

Comment: Thanks, what you said makes sense.  However, using both cat -A and :set list in vi both only indicate an end of line ($) character at the end of each line, i.e., nothing visibly unique about that line.

Comment: @Tiggyboo: Ah, but there is! See my updated answer. Lightly smacking yourself in the forehead is strictly optional, but it's certainly what I'd do.